# I am trying to make a script which updates wallpapers. It is giving my OSError

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, automation, oserror

This is a snippet from my code:

```
def set_background(image):
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, image , 0)

def set_wall(message):
    img = Image.new('RGB', auto.size(), color = (66, 70, 82))
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\consolab.ttf', 40)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    d.text((250, 330), message, font=fnt, fill=(171, 220, 255))
    wall_path = 'E:\\pranil\\python\\jee_wallpaper.png'
    img.save(wall_path)
    set_background(wall_path)

while True:
    if datetime.today().second == 0:
        message = calculate_rem_time()  
        set_wall(message)
```

The error I am getting is:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\pranil\python\jee_wallpaper.png'

How to solve this error?

EDIT:
I solved the problem..I just added time.sleep(1) between img.save(wall_path) and set_background(wall_path)

Answer (score 0):

Change the wall_path to

wall_path = 'E:\pranil\python\jee_wallpaper.png'

Comment: That is wrong, you must escape the backslash inside the string.

Comment: or you can use a r string

Answer (score 0):

OSErrors are usually caused by system related errors (eg. file not found, disk full, etc.). In your case your file paths look wrong. Try copying and pasting the file paths of the image files by right clicking the file and then select properties. Copy and paste the file path listed in Location: C:....

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats